# Axios PUT and DELETE methods resulting in 404 error (React)

Tags: reactjs, axios

I receive 404 errors while attempting to make PUT or DELETE requests with Axios. I simplified my code by removing useForm hooks and tried adding a custom config to the requests to no avail. Axios POST and GET requests are working.

```
import axios from "axios";

export default function Test() {
  const obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  const email = obj[0].email;
  const firstName = obj[0].firstName;
  const lastName = obj[0].lastName;
  const password = obj[0].password;
  const dateOfBirth = obj[0].dateOfBirth;
  const gender = obj[0].gender;
  const id = obj[0].id;
  const URL = "http://localhost:5000/users?email=" + email;

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.delete(URL, {data:{
      firstName: firstName, 
      lastName: lastName, 
      email: email, 
      password: password, 
      gender: gender,
      dateOfBirth: dateOfBirth,
      id: id,
    }, headers:{Authorization: "token"}})
    const response = axios.get(URL)
    return (response.data)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <button type="submit">DELETE ACCOUNT</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

I'm using axios version 0.27.2 and react version 18.0.

Comment: I think there is problem on the API server.
If the method is invalid you will get 405 error not 404 error.

Comment: I'm using JSON server. I receive GET requests without an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Postman and played around with making GET, POST, and PUT requests.

Although I could make GET requests from a URL of "http://localhost:5000/users?email={email}" I could not make PUT or DELETE requests without receiving a 404 error of Not Found.

I changed the URL to "http://localhost:5000/users/{id}" and no longer receive any errors for GET, PUT, or DELETE. I haven't tried all methods, however, I believe id is likely the best practice.

I still am unaware of why using a key results in a 404 error.